# Fourier expansion, mistake?

Tags: real-analysis

> Give the Fourier **sinus** series of $x(\pi -x ) \quad (0<x<\pi)$.

I started calculating the coefficients $b_n$:

$b_n = \frac2\pi \int_0^\pi x(\pi-x)\sin(2nx) dx = \frac2\pi \int_0^\pi (x\pi-x^2)\sin(2nx) dx = \frac2\pi \left( \frac{-1}{2n}[(x\pi-x^2)\cos(2nx)]_0^{\pi} 
 + \frac{1}{2n}\int_0^\pi (-2x+\pi)\cos(2nx)dx\right) $ $= \frac1{\pi n}\int_0^\pi(-2x+\pi)\cos(2nx)dx = \frac{1}{\pi n} \left( \frac{1}{2n}[(-2x+\pi)\sin(2nx)]_0^\pi+ \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\pi \sin(2nx)dx\right)$ $= \frac{-1}{2\pi n^3}[\cos(2nx)]_0^\pi = 0.$

How come I get $0$? Does anybody see my mistake?

I tried the same for $a_n$ and $a_0$. I found $a_n = 0$ and $a_0 = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$. So assuming these values to be true, would imply that the series is just the constant $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you use $\sin 2nx$ instead of $\sin nx$? It does not form an orthonormal basis. Note that we can extend the given function uniquely to an odd function on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: Isn't the formula $b_n = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$? In the example $L$ equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Umm ... you are missing that we need cosine terms when $L=\frac{\pi}{2}$. As I said, extend $f$ to $(-\pi,\pi)$ and regard as if $L=\pi$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0+} x(\pi-x) = 0$. So when extending the function, can I pick $F(x) = 0$ for $-\pi < x < 0$?

Comment: I'll give you more details: Our goal is to write $f=\sum_n b_n \sin nx$ for $0<x<\pi$. Since we exclude cosine series, the RHS is an odd function. Hence if we can write $f$ as a sine seires, then it should also be true that $\tilde{f}(x) = \sum_n b_n \sin nx$ for $|x|<\pi$ where $\tilde{f}$ is an odd extension of $f$. Now, $b_n =1/\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \tilde{f}(x)\sin nxdx = 2/\pi \int_{0}^\pi f(x)\sin nxdx.$

Comment: Is this a good option? $F(x) = \begin{cases} x(\pi-x) & 0<x<\pi \\ x(\pi+x) & -\pi<x<0 \end{cases}$.

Comment: Yes, it's good!